# Wrong font for some unicode characters

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, unicode, i3

I have been experiencing some issues with how my terminal shows some of the Unicode characters form my language.

The picture shows the issue in the editor in the left terminal. It seems like some of the characters are shown in a wrong font.

A note to be made is that this issue seems to have started after I installed AwesomeFont (from Nautilus - Install Font), but this might not be correlated.

I am using Ubuntu, my window manager is I3.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the same font throughout the uncolored characters.

Comment: Have you checked that the font you told the terminal emulator to use actually contains the letters `e`, `c` and `r` with caron? Because if it doesn't, you cannot blame the terminal emulator for doing it's best to show the letters by picking them from some other font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the terminal font (depends on terminal, probably xterm)

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/5qly20/how_do_you_change_i3wm_terminal_font_and/

Or uninstall AwesomeFont, since that's the latest change.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue! Removing AwesomeFont 5 and replacing it by AwesomeFont 4.7 didn't work, but after changing my GNOME terminal font from Courier to Liberation Mono, everything worked. [Here is the resource that I used to change the terminal font.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58379/how-can-i-permanently-change-the-text-size-for-gnome-terminal)